# Date formatter Mon, 03 May 2021 00:00:00 GMT

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I want to convert this `String` to `Date`

`Mon, 03 May 2021 00:00:00 GMT`

```
let dateString = "Mon, 03 May 2021 00:00:00 GMT"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss 'Z'"
date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
```

but it doesn't work, `date` is nil. So what is the correct format for this case?

Comment: "EEE, dd MM yyyy HH:mm:SSZ"?

Comment: You should show how your date string would display different timezones . Your dateFormat timezone `Z` might be wrong. https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkYVY.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the date format as like `EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss Z`

```
        let dateString = "Mon, 03 May 2021 00:00:00 GMT"
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss Z"
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
        print(date)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use HH since this is 24h format and since the day and month names are in English you also need to set the locale for the formatter so it doesn't use the users current locale

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
```

Comment: Setting the locale made a difference for me. It was returning nil for devices in different locales.
I also did set the time zone though as described in the docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter

"When working with fixed format dates, such as RFC 3339, you set the dateFormat property to specify a format string. For most fixed formats, you should also set the locale property to a POSIX locale ("en_US_POSIX"), and set the timeZone property to UTC."